# error using Meteor upload

Tags: meteor

i followed the [Meteor Upload](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) guide exactly , but i get this error when i load my uploading template.
any clues ?

```
    Exception from Tracker recompute function: Cannot read property 'autoStart' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoStart' of null
    at Template.upload.created (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/tomi_upload-jquery.js?b6bf3c0cc365d2eb8f9acc93ee3dcc4bfd892687:2569:29)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2995:20)
    at fireCallbacks (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1835:16)
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:513:12)
    at http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1832:13
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2043:12)
    at Object.Blaze._fireCallbacks (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1831:9)
    at Object.Blaze._createView (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1849:9)
    at Object.Blaze._materializeView (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1853:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it with Meteor for Windows and it works perfect for me.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/',
    checkCreateDirectories: true
  })
});
```

Check what you are getting at `process.env.PWD`, I think issues comes from your enviroment. You need write permissions to that path. Also check out latest updates with `meteor update`.

Btw, it can be issue with nitrous enviroment.